# Is rational to logical as rectangle is to square?

Tags: logic, rationality

That is, if X is logical, is it necessarily rational? What's an example of something that is rational, but not logical. If logical does not necessarily imply rational, what's an example of something that is logical, but not rational?

Comment: "What's an example of something that is rational, but not logical. " Kirk versus Spock. They must have done at least a dozen episodes directly on the theme.

Comment: Self-preservation is rational but not logical, insane people may follow some irrational logic. These words are too vague to say much without additional context, is this a class assignment?

Comment: No, I'm a law student. Totally out of curiosity.

Comment: Why would self-preservation be illogical?

Comment: It is neither logical nor illogical. Logic, on one conception, is about validly transforming premises to conclusions, self-preservation has nothing to do with that. Of course, people commonly use "logical" as a synonym of "makes sense to me" instead, which is why answering this question is like making out shapes in a cloud.

Comment: @Conifold Oh ok. What if I changed it to. 'Is it possible for X to rationally follow from Y, even if X does not necessarily follow from Y?'

Comment: "Rationally follow" and "necessarily follow" need explication just as "rational" and "logical" do. Once you specify the meanings with some precision the question will dissolve.

Comment: @Conifold well if X necessarily follows from Y, then I think that means that if Y is true, then X is true, right? I don't know what rationally follow means, I thought you philosophy people could help with that!

Comment: Squares and rectangles are species of tetragon; are you asking whether logic and rationality are species of some higher genus? Note that some philosophers have differentiated the rational from the reasonable. Arendt pointed out how mercilessly deductive totalitarian thinkers could be, how "logical" in a very bare sense; but she would probably have allowed that they were not quite as "reasonable"...

Comment: By RATIONAL what people tend to express is there is a REASON (be it a bad one or a great one) for a behavior in the practical world.  For instance if an elderly woman is falling to the floor she may straighten her arms out so she doesn’t hit her head to the floor. However her straightening her arm may cause serious injury to her arm.  Her actions were not LOGICAL. By LOGICAL we tend to mean that there are some rules or principles in DEDUCTIVE REASONING that can be named or referred to in our justification for a statement. So I would cite a RULE that can be verified as the reason for thinking

Comment: @KristianBerry well so a square is a type of rectangle, but a rectangle is not a type of square. What I'm trying to get at is what the technical difference between logical and rational is, and whether one implies the other.

Comment: @Logikal that makes sense.

Comment: Seems u are talking about "rational" as human character expressed in common language. In philosophy, rationalism is defined as a methodology or a theory in which the criterion of the truth is not sensory but intellectual and deductive. So in this context being rational is only sufficient to being logical, not necessary. As an empiricist who will also use logic to her advantage if needed. Rationalists just believe reasoning and logic are innate human characters to acquire knowledge like veined marbles, while empiricists believe human like a blanket paper with emphasis on experiences to do same.

Comment: "If Y is true, then X is true" is the material conditional of classical logic, but in real life contexts epistemic, heuristic or probabilistic logics are used instead. Can it be rational to draw a conclusion from true premises that is actually false? Sure, if the subject's knowledge is limited it may very well happen, see [abduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/) and [logical omniscience](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/#LogiOmni). But you'll be hard pressed to relate this to the liberal colloquial use of "rational" and "logical".

Comment: Self-preservation is illogical if you choose suicide. Self-destruction is necessary if you are depressive. Self preservation of a murderer has no logical coherence with self-preservation of the group. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the understanding of *rational*. The question scope is too broad, so it makes an ill-formed question for this forum.

In general, **something rational is just related to reason**. And reason is not always logical. For example, a lot of people make rational decisions (that is, they develop a set of reasons) which are not logical and lead to poverty. There, clearly, reason might contradict logic.

In formal disciplines, there are multiple understandings of the term *rational*. Often, it is directly associated with *logic*. Usually, the term *Rational* in a technical document describes the logic of the content. There, *logic* and *rational* are the same. But it depends on the discipline. In psychology, it could be the antonym of *unconscious*.

In philosophy, there are also multiple uses. *Rational*, for example, can be the opposite to *empirical*. In such case, comparing *logical* to *rational* would be comparing peaches with oranges.

In the same way, a rectangle can be or not as a square. A rectangle is as a square because both are geometric forms, but a rectangle IS NOT as a square because both have different forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that rational to logic is like draftsman's skills are to a setsquare with which he is able to draw a square.

Rationality means acting according to reason, so a rational person would be a person, that often acts according to her reason.

Now, your confusion is driven, I think, by the fact that classical logic is the most often used "tool of reason", if you will.

I can totally not use classical logic during my act, maybe I use some other logic or not a logic at all, but as long as my act is performed with the use of reason, and not some other faculty, this act should be called rational and not (classicaly) logical.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that both are poor approximations to truth.  Rational suggests that a ratio exists, for example the statement that one person in ten is left-handed.  Logical is typically used in the context of binary decisions, such as if you are old and you are a man then you are an old man.  So one is typically used in the context of real numbers and the other in the context of integers or natural numbers.  One might argue that natural numbers are a subset of real numbers, but I think that they behave quite differently and so it’s better to say that rational and logical are seperate things.